# Is it possible to get a word by word time stamp of a youtube video transcript programmatically?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I'm looking through the API docs trying to find one that matches what I'm looking for, which is to get a transcript of a video, and then be able to get the exact timestamp of one particular word from that transcript (not a sentence and not a paragraph).